# Systemd service that starts and preserves multiple processes

Tags: systemd

I want to create a systemd service that starts N identical copies of a process (as in, same arguments for each copy), and restarts any of them if they crash. It is okay if N is hardcoded in the service file.

Google suggests that templated/instantiated services can do this, but the examples I find are all of the form `systemctl start myservice@someid`, repeated for each process, which is not what I want. I want to be able to do `systemctl start myservice` and have it start all processes and keep them alive.

How do I do this correctly?

(I am porting this service from upstart, which requires two files to achieve this effect, one parent instantiating multiple children. That would be okay, albeit not ideal)

Comment: You could use a _target_ unit in combination with the template.  The target could _want_ or _require_ N instances of the template with different ids.  That would start all the services if you start the target, but not the other way around.  Systemd would keep the instances alive if the template is configured so.  I'm not sure if you find this good enough.